# Efficient text classification with large number (tens of thousands or more) of classes.

Tags: machine-learning

I'm working on a text classification problem in which the number of classes/labels is large (tens of thousands or more). What approaches/methods would you use? Can you point me towards any relevant papers?

Answer (score 0):

How long your text entities are? If they are document, then [Refined Experts](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1571946) is a very good work to look at given that you have large number of document classes. This work did experiment on more than 100 thousand classes but one important fact is the **classes are hierarchically organized**. They have used hierarchical SVM to build their classifier. SVM is good with large of classes if they are hierarchically organized. You can find lot of relevant works through Google scholar.

If your classes are not hierarchically organized, then you model your problem as n-binary classification problem. You may get some idea if you go through this [presentation](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiGtcz63L_QAhVJjFQKHdoWCB4QFggbMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.cs.cmu.edu%2F~rayid%2Ftalks%2FJobTalk.ppt&usg=AFQjCNE4selwFD3emVNZt_0DhWG2g_XjVg&sig2=IAf55-qIcXEAl38GiJcHzg).